# Delete TV episode from iTunes from iPhone without computer

Tags: iphone, itunes

How do I delete a TV episode off of my iPhone that I downloaded from iTunes. I don't want it to stay in my iTunes and I don't have a computer. So please what do I do? It has filled almost all the space on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Swap from right to left on the title of the episode and magically*, a Delete button will appear on the right hand side. You just have to tap on that Delete.

*:-)